# Is it possible to get account balances in --syncmode "fast"?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, nodes, balances

I want to get transaction details and account balance from Ethereum blockchain. The range of date is from genesis block to last mined.

- 1. Is it possible to get these information from web3.js?
- 2. Is it possible to get tx and balances from fast sync Eth node? (probably no, but please share your views)
- 3. Finally, do you suggest to migrate Ethereum block data to relational or non-relational traditional databases and query them for tx and balances?

Comment: with `"fast"` you only get what you download, i.e. only recent balances, you cant get the balance of an account at Genesis block with `fast` sync.

Comment: why do you need historical balances?